# Foreign key 'Nombre' invalid table 'Nombre_tabla'

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hola estoy generando mi primera base de datos a través de un ejercicio de práctica, ya tengo el código hecho, pero tengo errores en las llaves foráneas de las tablas me arroja lo siguiente Foreign key 'Nombre' invalid table 'Nombre_tabla', esto me pasa dentro de la tabla Administrador y Vetar que es donde se encuentran:

-En administrador, Foreign key 'fk_idc' invalid table Comunicacion'.
-En vetar, Foreign key 'fk_idservidor' invalid table 'Servidor' y Foreign key 'fk_idadv' invalid table 'Advertencia'.

Quisiera saber cual mi error, si en base a la sintaxis del código o que fue lo que hice mal, muchas gracias de antemano.

Aquí mi código:

```
create table Administrador(
nickname varchar(30) not null default 'Sin NickName',
nombre varchar (30) not null,
apellidos varchar (60) not null,
pais varchar(30) not null default 'Pais no registrado',
id_comunicacion int not null,
id_admin int not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_idmin PRIMARY KEY(id_admin),
CONSTRAINT fk_idc FOREIGN KEY(id_comunicacion) REFERENCES Comunicacion(id_comunicacion)
);

create table Vetar(
id_jugador int not null,
nickname varchar(30) not null default 'Sin Nickname',
fechayhsuceso varchar (50)not null,
tiempoban varchar(30) not null,
expiracion varchar(30) not null,
motivo varchar(50)not null default 'No Motivo',
totalvetos int not null,
id_servidor int not null,
id_admin int not null,
id_adv int not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_idjugador PRIMARY KEY(id_jugador),
CONSTRAINT fk_idservidor FOREIGN KEY (id_servidor) REFERENCES Servidor(id_servidor),
CONSTRAINT fk_idadmin FOREIGN KEY(id_admin) REFERENCES Administrador(id_admin),
CONSTRAINT fk_idadv FOREIGN KEY(id_adv) REFERENCES Advertencia(id_adv)
);

create table Servidor(
id_servidor int not null,
nombre varchar(30) not null,
smacdtc varchar(5) not null,
vacsec varchar(5) not null,
slots varchar(5)not null,
mapa varchar (25)not null default 'Mapa no disponible',
CONSTRAINT pk_idserv PRIMARY KEY(id_servidor)
);

create table Comunicacion(
id_comunicacion int not null,
red_social varchar(20) not null default 'Sin red social' ,
stat varchar (20) not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_com PRIMARY KEY(id_comunicacion),
);

create table Advertencia(
id_advertencia int not null,
mensaje varchar(30) not null default 'Sin mensaje',
CONSTRAINT pk_adv PRIMARY KEY(id_advertencia)
);
```

Comment: El orden en que se crean las tablas influye. Si cuando creas la tabla Administrador no está creada la tabla Comunicacion, dificilmente podrás hacer referencia a ella. Pasa lo mismo en tus otros casos. Puedes crear todas las tablas en primer lugar solo con las claves primarias que son obligatorias y luego crear las restricciones de clave foranea en sentencias distintas de alter.

Comment: @RubioRic puedes poner eso como una respuesta.

Comment: @SJuan76 Hecho!

Answer (score 1):

Imaginemos que la base de datos está vacía,no tiene ninguna tabla, antes de que se ejecuten tus sentencias de creación.

```
create table Administrador (
nickname varchar(30) not null default 'Sin NickName',
nombre varchar (30) not null,
apellidos varchar (60) not null,
pais varchar(30) not null default 'Pais no registrado',
id_comunicacion int not null,
id_admin int not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_idmin PRIMARY KEY(id_admin),
CONSTRAINT fk_idc FOREIGN KEY(id_comunicacion) REFERENCES Comunicacion(id_comunicacion)
);
```

Cuando lanzas esta sentencia, en la última línea estás indicando que el campo ID_COMUNICACION hace referencia al campo homónimo de la tabla COMUNICACION, pero dicha tabla no existe aún. Y es por ello que te salta el error.

¿Cómo solucionarlo? Tienes que lanzar todas las sentencias de creación **sin las restricciones (CONSTRAINT) de clave foránea (FOREIGN KEY)** y a continuación modificar cada una de las tablas para añadir esas restricciones.

La [sentencia necesaria](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) para modificar una tabla añadiéndole una restricción de clave foránea en MySQL tiene la siguiente sintaxis

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Aplicado a tu primer caso sería

```
ALTER TABLE Administrador ADD CONSTRAINT fk_idc FOREIGN KEY(id_comunicacion) REFERENCES Comunicacion(id_comunicacion);
```